# Find number of observations before 1st occurence of a condition in another Variable in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to answer Question 5.7.1.8 from Hadley Wickham's R for Data Science:

For each plane, count the number of flights before the first delay of greater than 1 hour.

There are 4,044 unique tailnum's as per below:

```
 flights %>% 
   group_by(tailnum) %>%
   summarise(flights = n())
# A tibble: 4,044 x 2
   tailnum flights
   <chr>     <int>
 1 D942DN        4
 2 N0EGMQ      371
 3 N10156      153
 4 N102UW       48
 5 N103US       46
 6 N104UW       47
 7 N10575      289
 8 N105UW       45
 9 N107US       41
10 N108UW       60
# ... with 4,034 more rows
```

Below I can see when Condition Criteria has been met:

```
flights %>%
   group_by(year, month, day, tailnum, arr_delay) %>%
   summarise(first_60_plus_delay = first(arr_delay > 60)) %>%
   arrange(tailnum)
# A tibble: 332,316 x 6
# Groups:   year, month, day, tailnum [251,727]
    year month   day tailnum arr_delay first_60_plus_delay
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>       <dbl> <lgl>              
 1  2013     2    11 D942DN         91 TRUE               
 2  2013     3    23 D942DN         44 FALSE              
 3  2013     3    24 D942DN          2 FALSE              
 4  2013     7     5 D942DN        -11 FALSE              
 5  2013     1     1 N0EGMQ         17 FALSE              
 6  2013     1     1 N0EGMQ         67 TRUE               
 7  2013     1     2 N0EGMQ         -6 FALSE              
 8  2013     1     2 N0EGMQ         11 FALSE              
 9  2013     1     4 N0EGMQ         -2 FALSE              
10  2013     1     5 N0EGMQ        -15 FALSE              
# ... with 332,306 more rows
```

How do we now filter out FALSE occurences that occur after TRUE for each Tailnum?
Help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Rob

Comment: How do you get that `flights` data? I just skimmed through Ch 4 of R4DS but can't figure out how to load the data to work on this.

Comment: mysterRious, to get the flights data, load the packages: library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse). The flights dataset is in the nycflights13 library